# What is the best way of generating pdf in struts based web application?

Tags: struts, pdf-generation

I am using struts framework to develop the web application.

I have requirement to generate the PDF , which is also in various formats.

What is the best way to generate the PDF with lots of alignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iText** is a ***`free Java-PDF library`*** that allows you to generate **PDF** files **on the fly (dynamically)**. **iText** is an ideal library for developers looking to enhance web- and other applications with **dynamic PDF** document **generation** and/or **manipulation**. iText is not an end-user tool. Typically you won’t use it on your Desktop as you would use Acrobat or any other PDF application. Rather, you’ll build iText into your own applications so that you can automate the PDF creation and manipulation process.

**iText (Java-PDF Library) can be used to:**

**1.** Serve PDF to a browser
**2.** Generate dynamic documents from XML files or databases
**3.** Use PDF’s many interactive features
**4.** Add bookmarks, page numbers, watermarks, etc.
**5.** Split, concatenate, and manipulate PDF pages
**6.** Automate filling out of PDF forms
**7.** Add digital signatures to a PDF file

Take a Look at these Stuffs

**[PDF Generation In Java Using IText JAR](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-pdf-file-in-java-using-itext-jar/)**

**[Creating Pdf By Using Struts2](http://lkreddy.blogspot.ae/2012/04/creating-pdf-by-using-struts2.html)**

**[Struts PDF Generating Example](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/pdfgeneratingexample.html)**

Answer (score 0):

iText is the good way to develop PDF with lot of alignments. This library allows lot of control over individual elements and positioning. Further it has good online support

[iText Library](http://itextpdf.com/)